# Lightweighted mySQL server?

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

I have very limited resources (RAM) on my server (Debian lenny) and I need to install mySQL server, it will not be extensively used. I installed `apt-get install mysql-server` before but it was taking about 150MB of RAM and I am looking for alternative servers, are there any, I couldn't find anything.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: SQL is a resource intensive service. The only option you really have is to increase your resources. Not positive about MySQL, but I know the MSSQL will also reserve all available system resources.

Comment: @Mike Soule: MSSQL tends to grab a proportion of the memory by default; MySQL does not have this default, its memory usage is configured in its config file.

Comment: You might find this link useful: http://www.lowendbox.com/blog/reducing-mysql-memory-usage-for-low-end-boxes/ It describes configuration of MySQL for VPSes with limited memory (64MB).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can certainly be tuned to use less ram than the default. In particular, Debian may ship it with a configuration which is more suitable for a typical server-grade machine.

If you feel the need to run MySQL on a very memory-constrained platform, consider tuning its memory usage as described [here: How MySQL Uses Memory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/memory-use.html)

You probably want to use InnoDB; the most important thing to tune is to make your innodb_buffer_pool a sensible size (There are other InnoDB buffers you may want to tune too; read its documentation).

If you aren't using MyISAM, reduce its key_buffer_size to a small value (say 4M). MyISAM can't be disabled as it's used internally.

If you aren't using InnoDB, turn it off entirely.